# How to change gallery thumbnails' size with window?

Tags: html, css, image, resize, window

I've been trying to solve this problem for the last couple of hours but can't find any solution. I have four pictures that I want to use as photo gallery thumbnails. I want two of these pictures to be on the top and two of them on the bottom with no gaps or white spaces between them. Also, I want all these four pictures to resize as the window size changes so they will always cover the whole screen. Is this possible? After I do this, I will also add a menu bar to the left. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's how far I've gotten so far;
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ilkergoksen/TyQNB/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><img src="image1" /></li>
    <li><img src="image1" /></li>
    <li><img src="image1" /></li>
    <li><img src="image1" /></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline ;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Thank you,

Ilker

Answer (score 0):

To **remove white space**, just add:

```
ul li{
..
line-heigth: 0;
..
}
```

---

To **resize** the first two images, give them `width: 50%;` , then    `width: 100%;` for the others.

---

If this is not the answer you are looking for please provide details about the sizing problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I am looking for. I need a setup like on Vivian Maier's website; http://www.vivianmaier.com/

But instead of 3 photos in one row, I'll have 2. Thank you.